# Why can this function not use opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, opacity

I would like to make the image a little transparent for a short time by pressing the button and then make it visible again normally. Why does the code not work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    img {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="epicenter">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Face-devil-grin.svg/1024px-Face-devil-grin.svg.png" alt="Schwarz" id="black">
    </div>
    <button onclick="test()">Test</button>
    
    <script>
    function sleep(miliseconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
    }
    }
    
    function test() {
    document.getElementById("black").style.opacity = "0.33";
    sleep(3000);
    document.getElementById("black").style.opacity = "1";
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is much simpler.

```js
function test() {
  const el = document.getElementById('black');
  el.style.opacity = '0.33';
  setTimeout(() => el.style.opacity = '1', 3000);
}
```

```css
img  width: 128px height: 128px padding: 10px; }
img:hover { opacity: 0.5; }
```

```html
<div id="epicenter">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Face-devil-grin.svg/1024px-Face-devil-grin.svg.png" alt="Schwarz" id="black">
</div>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use SetTimeout instead of defining your own sleep function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("black").style.opacity = 1;
}, 3000);
```

Replace your sleep function call with the above.

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals for more details